# joining tables in active records ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have two tables, table1

```
id   name   age   occupation  ssn_id 
1    A      18    engineer    12
2    B      19    engineer    67
3    C      14    student     89
4    B      19    engineer    67
```

table2

```
id   ssn_id  limit   hours
1    67      2       20
2    12      2       17
3    89      2       78
```

Expexted output

```
ssn_id  limit  count(*)  occupation
67      2      2         engineer
```

Sql query -

```
select id, occupation, count(*) as TOTAL, `limit` from table1*table2 where table1.ssn_id = table2.ssn_id and occupation = 'engineer' group by table1.ssn_id  having count(*) > `limit`
```

I want to convert this query to Rails Active Record Query. I have tried using include but I can't get the columns of second table.

Comment: what did you mean by **I want to convert this query to active records.** ?

Comment: I want to convert this query to rails active record query. Have edited the question

Answer (score 1):

If you have models for Table1 and Table2, you can use this approach:

```
 Table1.
   joins(:table2).
   select("table1.id, table1.occupation, count(*) as TOTAL, table2.limit").
   where(occupation: 'engineer').where("table1.ssn_id = table2.ssn_id").
   group(table1.ssn_id).
   having("count(*) > limit")
```

Comment: It throws a `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'table1' for main:Object`